# Polylogarithmic integrals

Tags: integration, mathematics

NB: I was sent here from Math.SE, stating that polylog integrals are more common in physics and someone here might have an answer. I have asked in Phys.SE chat whether it was okay to post here but no response, so I just posted.

I'm currently looking into the Lieb-Liniger model. The Fredholm inverse of the Cauchy Kernel appears to contain integrals of the form
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{\operatorname{Li}_\nu(\frac{\alpha}{\beta x + \gamma})}{\zeta x + \eta} dx
\end{equation}
with $\operatorname{Li}_\nu$ the polylogarithm of order $\nu$, defined as
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Li}_\nu(x) \equiv \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^\nu}.
\end{equation}

The above may for example be reduced using substitution $\alpha/(\beta x+\gamma) = \alpha\zeta u/(\zeta\gamma-\beta\eta)$:
\begin{equation}
\frac\beta\zeta \left\{ \int \frac{\operatorname{Li}_\nu\left(\frac{\alpha\zeta u}{\zeta\gamma - \beta\eta}\right)}{1-u}du + \int \frac{\operatorname{Li}_\nu\left(\frac{\alpha\zeta u}{\zeta\gamma - \beta\eta}\right)}{u}du \right\},
\end{equation}
but sadly this only elucidates what one of the terms in the expansion is going to be, and the first term in parentheses has a huge numbers of resulting terms (i.e. after doing the integral, and it has more than 10 at least).

My question is simple. I would like to recast these integrals into some form that simplifies the result of the integrals. For example the "normal" logarithm obeys the equality
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{\log(\alpha-x)}{x-\beta} dx = \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{\alpha - x}{\alpha-\beta}\right) + \log(\alpha - x) \log\left(\frac{x-\beta}{\alpha-\beta}\right)
\end{equation}
which is a very tractable expression for a complicated integral. I would like to find a little simpler expressions for the higher order logarithms as well. Does anyone know of reading material that has the information I need? Or can anyone see a good substitution that gives a result of say, 5 terms, or 2 instead of >10?

Comment: Give a definition for $Li_{\nu }(x)$

Comment: For people checking this out much later. I have figured out the derivation for $Li_2(x)$, and it turns out that the above is due to the fact that two polynomials of degree 1 may be written in terms of each other. As such both can be written as a multiple of each other using conventional scaling/stretching etc. properties. This means that a form of integral over $Li_1(x)$ as above, may have a two term solution. The dilogarithm possesses what appears to be an accidental symmetry that allows it to be integrated in closed from using only logarithms, a symmetry not apparent in $Li_3(x)$. TBC.